# Set Focus to First Cell in DataGrid Code-Behind WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

I have a data grid (using a datagrid template with textboxes as the cells) in a WPF MVVM application that is bound to a collection of objects.  The data grid is simple, only has 2 columns ("Name" and "Year").  The window has a Input button that once clicked, inserts a blank row at the beginning of the collection and thus the beginning of the data grid.

XAML

```
<Button Name="InsertButton" Command="{Binding InsertCommand}" />
```

ViewModel

```
public ViewModel()
{
    InsertCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnInsert);
}

private void OnInsert(object obj)
{
    MyList.Insert(0, new MyItem());
}
```

This works with an MVVM setup, but it wondering if there is a way to set focus the first cell's textbox each time the insert button is clicked, and to program it in the XAML code behind instead of using MVVM?

Thanks

Comment: Please post your XAML markup.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution would be to implement multiple commands with Button Click.
Here is an approach on how to do that.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25808/Aggregating-WPF-Commands-with-CommandGroup. 
After doing that, implement the second command in code-behind which could have the code to enable the Focus on the required element using ".Focus()" method of UIElement.

Another approach would be to raise an event in the ViewModel at the end of OnInsert method which would be handled in the code behind to set the .Focus() on the required UIElement.